# Magento2 : Adding simple products to configurable product via admin

Tags: magento2, admin, configurable-product

I just did a demo migration using cart2cart.

It created some configurable products as well as simple products that are supposed to be associated with them.

The simple products however are not associated in any way with the configurable products and I can't seem to find a way to do so.

This is magento 2.1.3. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you found a way yet to add already existing simple products to a configurable product?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 you need to first use the "Create configurations" tool to create the simple products to associate, then you need to replace the auto-generated versions with the simple products you actually want.
[image]

Comment: Tried this and for unknown to me reason when trying to add an existing simple product to the list the associated product list has the product with disabled check box so I cannot select it!

Comment: Found the solution. Do not remove and try to add but rather from the menu select assign a different product!

Comment: @George Hey, where did you find "assign a different product"? 
Is it in the simple product? What was this one?

Comment: @MJoraid It was some time but in essence I believe you need to first go through the steps to add simple products in a configurable so that the list is not empty. Then re-load the configurable and now you can assign other products. Don't quote me, what I recall anyways

Answer (score -1):

Get into the designated configuration product, under `Configurations` select `Add Products Manually`

Comment: Under configurations there is only one button to "create configurations"

Comment: @Sackling, having same issue. Link is completely missing. You find a fix for this?